# Google crawling angularjs site strangley

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-search

I'm having some trouble identifying why Google is crawling links that don't exist on my angularjs site. I'm using prerender.io which takes a snapshot of the page and returns it to the search bot. For example google will correctly list in the search results:

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/string/string2
```

but then it will randomly create another link to crawl such as:

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/string/string2/string/string3
```

which doesn't even exist!

In the end I get these long urls which are shown in the search results for my site but don't actually display anything useful.

I think the problem is caused by the tag base href="/" - as google will see a header link for example on the page /string1/string2 and then take the base root as it currently is and append the header link to it- i.e. /string1/string2/string1/string2.

Does anyone know if this is the problem and how I can combat this apart from putting in absolute links and removing angular from the equation?

I've tried removing the urls in google webmaster tools but this is time consuming and unreliable as there are so many links and I've added to the robots.txt file the disallowed links but they still show up in google with a message about robots.txt.

Any ideas here?

Thanks!